# Does enabling CICP activity logging log activity for Firebase authentication?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

My project uses Firebase authentication.

I want to enable the logging of authentication activity for compliance. Google has this feature for its Google Cloud CICP (Cloud Identity for Customers and Partners) ([documentation here](https://cloud.google.com/identity-cp/docs/how-to-activity-logging)).

I know that CICP says it's compatible with Firebase authentication, but does this mean it will log my Firebase project's authentication activity if I do enable it? Or will it only log activity from accounts created directly by CICP? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Stackdriver activity logging, it will work for activity across both CICP and Firebase Auth. As you've probably seen from the documentation, the first step is to enable this on your project:

```
curl -d "{'monitoring':{'requestLogging':{'enabled':true}}}" -H 'Authorization: Bearer [AUTH_TOKEN]' -X PATCH -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/admin/v2/projects/[PROJECT_ID]/config?updateMask=monitoring.requestLogging.enabled
```

- You can get an AUTH_TOKEN any number of ways, but a simple method is using the [Google OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) and authorizing the Google Identity Toolkit API v3 scopes.

Once you have some activity that's worthy of reviewing, you can check it out directly in [StackDriver logs viewer](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer) within the "Identity Toolkit Project" resource.

One thing to be aware of is that if you have a large number of users, or really significant activity on your project, you might also want to specify exclusions to minimize cost/traffic/noise. Details are included in the [Activity Logging](https://cloud.google.com/identity-cp/docs/how-to-activity-logging) docs you've specified.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I was worried enabling that would only be for accounts created by CICP. This is great news!

Comment: Awesome - no worries at all, let me know how you go.